# How do I solve this equation $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So, I was thinking about the substitution $x=\tan\frac{z}{2}$, $x∈(−π;π)$ which leads to $\arccos(-\cos{z})+\frac{1}{2} \cdot \arctan(\tan{z})=\frac{2\pi}{3} \implies \arccos(\cos(\pi-z))+\frac{1}{2} \cdot \arctan(\tan{z})=\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Here we now consider four cases - the belonging of $z$ to different quarters.

Comment: Consider $z\in(-\pi/2,0  ), [0,\pi/2), [\pi/2, \pi] $ and the intervals you get by shifting these by $2n\pi$.

Comment: Note that you can assume $z \in (-\pi,\pi)$, since $\tan(z/2)$ maps this interval to the whole real line.

Comment: Also, you've made an error in your trig identities. It should be $\arccos(-\cos(z)) = \pi - \arccos(\cos(z))$

Comment: @eyeballfrog thanks, i fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\cos^{-1}\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}=2y\implies0\le2y\le\pi$

$$x^2=\dfrac{1+\cos2y}{1-\cos2y}=\cot^2y$$

**Case**$\#1:$

If $x<0, x=-\cot y$

$$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}=\tan^{-1}(\tan2y)=\begin{cases}2y &\mbox{if } 2y\le\dfrac\pi2  \\-\pi+2y & \mbox{otherwise }  \end{cases}$$

So if $2y\le\dfrac\pi2,$ the LHS $=2y+y=\dfrac{2\pi}3, y=?$

Otherwise LHS $=2y+\dfrac{-\pi+2y}2$

**Case**$\#2:$

If $x\ge0, x=+\cot y$

$$\tan^{-1}\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}=\tan^{-1}(-\tan2y)=-\tan^{-1}(\tan2y)$$

$\tan^{-1}(\tan2y)$ can be calculated like **Case**$\#1:$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: You are a little late) I solved this equation a long time ago. And yes, I can, thanks!

Comment: @Rene, Welcome. Nice to hear that you solved it yourself. Please feel free to share your approach in case it is different from the existing solutions